# Vim - jump back to previous position when moving multiple lines at once

Tags: list, vim, line

When I use Vim, I often times use motions commands when moving lines.
For example if I want to move 20 lines down, I press `20j`.
Now after having "jumped" 20 lines down, if I want to go back again to my previous position, I have to enter `20k`.

Is there a way to jump to my previous position without typing `20k`?
For example, by somehow adding the previous position to Vims jump list, then I could use `<c-o>` to jump back.

(By the way, I only want to jump back when I move more that one line at once).

Comment: [double backtick](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%60%60)

Comment: The plugin [jk-jumps](https://github.com/teranex/jk-jumps.vim) adds j/k jumps to the jump-list. then you can back to previous position using `<c-o>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the following on my `~/.vimrc` file :

```
" It adds motions like 25j and 30k to the jump list, so you can cycle
" through them with control-o and control-i.
" source: https://www.vi-improved.org/vim-tips/
nnoremap <expr> j v:count ? (v:count > 5 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'j' : 'gj'
nnoremap <expr> k v:count ? (v:count > 5 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'k' : 'gk'
```

In my case, line movements bigger than 5 lines are added to the jump list.

Comment: This solution spoils all other convenient commands of vim like `<count>dj`, `<count>yk`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The problem, here, is that `j` and `k` are not "jumps". When you do `20j` you are really doing `jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj` but very quickly so you would have to turn those arbitrary motions into proper jumps for `<C-o>` to work. How to do so is explained under `:help jumplist`:

> You can explicitly add a jump by setting the ' mark with "m'".

In practice:

```
m'20j
```

then `<C-o>` or `''` or ``` `` ``` to go back.

There are smarter ways to move around, though, that don't require you to count lines and that are actual jumps, like `:help /` and `:help ?`.

Comment: *"There are smarter ways to move around that don't require you to count lines"* Of course - `relativenumbers` most of all (alongside `/` and `?`).

Comment: Well no, relative numbers are just as dumb as plain numbers… and they are still not jumps, which is the whole point, here.

Comment: *"as dumb as plain numbers"* - defend that opinion having the same text pattern in multiple intermediate spots before your target spot on a distant line.